# Returning a more verbose error in production environment (DEBUG=False)

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm using tastypie, suppose that I have a model named M and a field in it - F - is unique CharField. Suppose that there's already an instance of M that its F value is "test", if I try to create another instance of M that has the same value for F or if I try to update an already created instance of M and change its F value to "test", tastypie returns an error and tells that `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "M_F_key"\nDETAIL:  Key (F)=(test) already exists.\n` but if I set DEBUG=False in settings it doesn't return that error an instead it returns `Sorry, this request could not be processed. Please try again later.` this way my client can't understand that the problem was a duplicate value for F field and can't show the user appropriate message. How can I solve this?

Comment: This is because Django is showing you the entire exception and trace when it encounters an error during debug. Once you are in production it just shows the http 500 placeholder page. You shouldn't pass exceptions onto the end user. You should instead try to catch the exceptions you are interested in (in this case a `IntegrityError`) and relate more user-friendly information on why it failed (or maybe an error code they can relay to you)

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony yeah, it seems rational, should I reimplement the update and create methods of my resource? or is there an easier way to catch the error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be solved by using a django middleware that implements `process_exception`